# Google Maps v3 issue

Tags: google-maps, maps, google-maps-markers

I have a map that pulls coordinates, infowindow data and create arrow headed marker from a Oracle database. It has about 400 markers. Last evening it was fine. But now the users are complaining that all markers are stacked together. What may be the reason??

Comment: Do you use experimental version of Google Maps API library?

Comment: There was already one almost the same question asked today (`.../22164896/google-maps-api-markers-with-label-all-stacked-in-one-place`). Root cause of the problem was experimental version of API. Unfortunately, question is deleted.

Comment: Not true, 3.15 is the current release version now since last week and it appears that this is the cause.  Perhaps it *was* experimental when the original post was made.  Backdating to the 3.14 API fixes it

Comment: I have not mentioned a version. So it seems like it auto picks the latest version. I'll set the version check again in the live environment.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing this too on http://shipfinder.co

What is the website you are developing?

I have a temporary fix that reverts it back to the 3.14 release instead of the now current 3.15.

If you specify ?v=3.14 in the loading of the API this will fix it for now.